# How to Create Loading PopScreen With Image in blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, loading, splash-screen

I am newbie to Blackberry . i need some help. how to display loading popscreen in my main screen.?

Comment: Have you tried searching on this? Here is a couple of links to similar StackOverflow questions I got from searching: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801161/blackberry-loading-wait-screen-with-animation), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969114/blackberry-waiting-screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that extends PopupScreen and load it ... You will have then a loading popupscreen in your mainScreen