# How to show process bar in middle of the screen in Blackberry using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

How do I show the process bar in the middle of the Blackberry screen using Eclipse?

Comment: Can you please provide more information? What should the screen look like? Just the progress bar alone? Should it show on top of other things?

Comment: Please refer to this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503313/blackberry-application-loading-screen

Answer (score 0):

Am using this:

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH | FIELD_VCENTER);
ProgressBarField pbf = new ProgressBarField(0, 100, 50, USE_ALL_WIDTH);
vfm.add(pbf);
hfm.add(vfm);
add(hfm);
```