# BlackBerry progress dialog

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I want to show the user a progress dialog until a particular task is complete.

For example, after the user enters username and password it takes some time to connect as the username and password are validated.  I want to show the progress bar to the user while waiting.

Comment: you can use status dialogs: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/01/bb-java-dialog.html

Answer (score 2):

GaugeField percentGauge = new GaugeField("Percent: ", 1, 100, 29, GaugeField.PERCENT);

Comment: add percentGauge to your custom popup screen and push that screen as progress dialog.

Answer (score 0):

While user is waiting for response u can also show loader screen or an activity indicator.

check these:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-display-the-blackberry-loading-icon-manually/m-p/552833

[Blackberry - Application loading screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503313/blackberry-application-loading-screen)

[Blackberry - Loading/Wait screen with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801161/blackberry-loading-wait-screen-with-animation)

May be it can help u.