# Creating custom progressbar in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

All, I want to crate an rich looking, custom progress bar for blackberry touch devices. I can used GaugeField, but it wont give the the rich look.

Here is sample prototype I have to make. Please suggest me how could I start with. Any sample or guide me with the steps.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [BlackBerry progress dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941477/blackberry-progress-dialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the "Creating a bitmap progress indicator" section of RIM's ["Advanced UI components and managers"](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/java/documentation/ww_java_uinavigation/Advanced_UI_components_and_managers_1970227_11.html) documentation.